# Adding data to attribute table based on other shapefiles within certain distance using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table

I have 3 feature classes. 2 of them are different types of water bodies (1 for polygons and 1 for lines), the other feature class contains locations of storage tanks. In the storage tank feature class, I am trying populate a column in the attribute table called Waterbody. It is supposed to contain the names of water bodies that are within a 2 mile radius of the storage tank. (see below)

[image: Storage Tank Attribute Table]

Each of the 2 feature classes of water bodies contain similar attributes which give the name of the waterbody.(see below)

[image: Waterbody attribute tables]

I have made a buffer for the Storage Tanks feature class, with the radius set to 2 miles but I'm not sure how I should go about getting the data in the attribute table. See below for an idea of what I am working with.

[image]

The points are the storage tank locations, the green "circles" are the buffers and the lines and irregular shaped polygons are the water bodies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to run the Spatial Join tool with the storage tank points or buffers as the target (the spatial Join tool can buffer the points in the settings of the tool, but you may find that using the buffer tool is faster).  You would need to run the tool using the polygons and lines as the join features in two separate runs.  You would change the properties of the GNIS_Name field in the field mapping to expand the number of characters in the text field to at least 255 and use the Join rule and then set the delimiter character to be something like a comma or semi-colon.  Then you could join the two outputs on the Target_ID fields and calculate a concatenation of the two GNIS_Name lists.  Then join to your original points on the ObjectID to either the Buffer FID or Spatial Join Target_ID (depending on what you used as the Target in the Spatial Join tool) and calculate the list into the GNIS_Name field of the points.  You could use the field calculator to also sort the GNIS_Name lists and eliminate duplicate values from the list.

Comment: You do have access to the Spatial Join tool since it is available for all license levels.  http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm

Comment: Yup, sorry. I was confused for a second there :)  I'm working on it now and will mark your answer as accepted once I get it to work. Thanks again!!